# What if I add a user to a supplementary group?

Tags: permissions, security, users, group

I am using debian 7.0 and I added "debian-transmission" to the group "pi" with:

```
usermod -a -G pi debian-transmission
```

I made this change because transmission was not able to write the pi mounted hdd.
Later I realised that pi is also belongs to sudo. My question is: does debian-transmission belong also to sudo supplementary group just because became to member of pi group which belongs to sudo, or with the above mentioned command I put only the member of pi group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are getting confused between the `pi` user and the `pi` group. You cannot add a group to a group, only users. There is a group with the same name as a user, the groups the user is in have no effect on the users that are in the group.